# Parsing out data from files (Python): How to determine the number of republicans, democrats and independents in the 114th congress

Tags: python

So, I have been working on this bit of code to determine the number of senators from the 114th congress who were republicans, democrats, and independents. Here's my code. For some reason, I keep getting funky errors regarding my variables that start with num. Please help.

```
def main():
    # Determines the number of senators of each party affiliation
    infile = open("Senate114.txt", 'r')
    set1 = {line.rstrip() + "\n" for line in infile}
    infile.close()
    listx = list(set1)
    listx.sort(key=lambda x: x.split(',')[2])  # sort by party affiliation
    partyAffiliation = listx[2]
    rep = []
    dem = []
    ind = []
    numRep = []
    numDen = []
    numInd = []
    while (partyAffiliation == 'R'):
        rep = rep.expend
        numRep == int(len(rep))
    while (partyAffiliation == 'D'):
        dem = dem.extend
        numDem == int(len(dem))
    while (partyAffiliation == 'I',):
        ind = ind.extend
        numInd == int(len(ind))

    print('Party Affiliation: ')
    print('Republicans: ',numRep)
    print('Democrats:' ,numDem)
    print('Independents:' ,numInd)

main()
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide an example of what your data looks like?

Comment: There is no FunkyError in python's doc...So, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your statements using the variables beginning with `num`, such as `numRep == int(len(rep))` are checking for equivalency, not assigning to the variable. Make it `numRep = int(len(rep))`

Comment: the data looks as follows: senator name, state, party affiliation                  ex: Ted Cruz, Texas, R  I also made the suggested change by coralv and got the following error message:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MaryAnn/Desktop/Quiz3/4b.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/MaryAnn/Desktop/Quiz3/4b.py", line 20, in main
    numInd = int(len(ind))
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()

Answer (score 2):

Assuming data that looks similar to this:

```
Gooding,Cuba,R
Miller,Dennis,D
Bolton,Michael,I
Grouch,Oscar,I
Einstein,Albert,R
Azaria,Hank,D
Motzart,Amadeus,I
```

You can use code like the following:

```
import collections

lines = open("Senate114.txt").read().splitlines()
parties = [line.split(",")[2] for line in lines]
party_counts = collections.Counter(parties)

print(party_counts)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Counter({'I': 3, 'R': 2, 'D': 2})
```

You could add on:

```
print('Party Affiliations: ')
print('Republicans:', party_counts.get('R', 0))
print('Democrats:', party_counts.get('D', 0))
print('Independents:', party_counts.get('I', 0))
```

Comment: Do I +1 for a good answer, or -1 for that corrupted data set? Ach, decisions... ;)

Comment: what is collections?

Comment: Collections is a built-in python module that contains various helpful modules / classes.  Counter is a part of collections and is useful when... counting things.  Read about it here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html